# Apache ignite docker container vs Linux service

Tags: ignite

I am concerned about the performance of ignite cache when running ignite sever as docker container and as Linux service.

And
Server - client approach vs ignite thin driver approach.

Please guide me which approach is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question about `thick` vs `thin` comparison I can say that `thick` client is faster in general because it communicates with an entire cluster (it's affinity aware), it means that network overhead is smaller in that case. And it supports more features than `thin` client. But the drawback is that `thick` client is full-fledged member of a cluster, it's not as lightweight as `thin` client is.

The main idea about `Docker` is that `Docker` always has overheads compared to a pure `Linux` installation. It will be slower in general.

The main point here is that you should measure performance to understand client and deployment types suitable for your use-case. It's pretty difficult to give some piece of general advice about performance-related stuff.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no noticeable performance difference.

Comment: Using thick client is usually faster and offers more options, but it has a lot of other implications.

Comment: And this is why I am afraid of going with thick client

Answer (score 1):

Check [this section](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/deployment-modes#thick-vs-thin-clients) for tradeoffs between thick and thin clients. In short, the thick clients are faster and support all the Ignite APIs (at least for Java).